# Run impersonate in iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, windows-authentication, iisnode, ntlm-authentication

I have a nodejs server **s1** running on IIS (using iisnode).
I'm using http-proxy-middleware to forward an http request to another server **s2** (can't access that server from client because of cors).

**s2** needs windows credentials.
Someone told me that credentials tha are send to **s2** aren't the windows credentials from the http request but the credentials of the user that running **s1**. He says I need to use impersonate in order to forward the http credentials.

Is it right ?
How can I do it?

Comment: s1 run as application pool identity if you don't use impersonate. Then the credential is application pool identity when forward http request to s2. But if  you use impersonate, the identity is the account used to login s1.

Comment: OK. that's what my friend said. How can I use impersonation in iisnode?

Comment: I'm not an expert on iisnode. But you can  configure it on web.config. `<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="foo" password="bar"/>
</system.web>`

Comment: Which usernme and password should i give?

Comment: The credentials that s2 need. s1 will run application and forward request with identity of this account.

Comment: Problem is that I don't know how to do it?..

Comment: Server s2 is owned by you. Others cannot know anything about it.

Comment: S2 is not owned by me. In the client request to s1 I should have the user's credentials in my nodejs code because the request is done with useCredentails. How can I forward it to s2?

Comment: I'm not an expert on nodejs, you can wait for other nodejs members. But settings on IIS are these all.

Comment: thank you for your help. I don't really understand the settings in iis which credentials should I set ? Is it safe to expose credentials like this?

Comment: The simplest credential is account you used to login s2 such as administrator. It is unsafe to expose adminstrator, so it's better to create a custom user or group on s2 group policy and set some restriction for it. Then you can expose it and no need to worry about security.